# How can I make fread work properly in C? It fills my dynamic array with zeroes

Tags: c, fread

I'm writing a c program that needs to read a binary file, put it into the array of structures and then sort this array.
Structure:

```
#define NCHAR 64

typedef
    struct data_
    {
        char country[NCHAR];
        long int population;
        float world_share;
    }
data;
```

All this happens in one separate function,that uses `freed()` to get the array form the file. And this function does not really works.
What i expect to see:

```
CountryA        100    10%
CountryB        200    20%
```

What i actually i get:

```
0        0    0%
0        0    0%
```

Can you please take a look what i am doing wrong? I've tried rewriting my code and could and searching for uses of `fread()` function but it seems like i am using it right.

```
void SortAndDisplayASC( void )//main
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    long size = fsize(worldData);
    int amount = size / sizeof(data);
    data * countries;
    countries = (data *) malloc(size);
    fread(countries, sizeof(data), amount, worldData); //PROBLEM HERE!
    sortByPopulation(countries, amount);
    for(int i = 0; i < amount;  i ++)
    {
        PrintData(countries[i]);
    }
    free(countries);
    fclose(worldData);
}
```

If you will to help me, i'll share the whole code.

### Post Scriptum:

Hello to all who happen to stumble in this question.
At the moment of writing it was my C assignment.
I have found and fixed the bug in my code back then and forgot to post it.
Now I need to post a new question and this one caught my attention. Here is the source code of this question. This version should work fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCHAR 64
#define WPOP 7800000000L

typedef
    struct data_
    {
        char country[NCHAR];
        long int population;
        float world_share;
    }
data;

void menu(int option);
//1st choise
void EnterAndWrite( void );
void ScanData(data * subject);
//2nd choise
void ReadTheCountry( void );
void PrintData(data subject);
//3rd choise
void SortAndDisplayASC( void );
long fsize(FILE * f);
void sortByPopulation(data *array, int n);
void dataArrayItemSwap(data *array, int a, int b);
//4th choise
void SortAndDisplayDSC( void );
void dataArrayFlip(data *array, int length);
//5th choise
void SearchForCountry( void );
void findByName(data * array, int n);
int myStrcmp(char * s1, char * s2);
//6th choise
void CompareDataWithWPOP();

int main(void)
{
    int option;
    do
    {
        printf( " (*) Here you will be able do persform several actions over the file world.dat\n\n"
                " (*) Enter 1 to enter the data of new country that will be added to file.\n"
                " (*) Enter 2 to enter the position of the country in the file that you want to see.\n"
                " (*) Enter 3 to show the database sorted by population in asceding order.\n"
                " (*) Enter 4 to show the database sorted by population in desceding order.\n"
                " (*) Enter 5 to search file for a specific country by its name or it's first lettes.\n"
                " (*) Enter 6 to see total population stored in DB and compare it with world population.\n"
                " (*) Enter 0 to teminate.\n");
        scanf("%d%*c", &option);
        menu(option);

    }while(option > 0);
    return 0;
}

void menu(int option)
{
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            EnterAndWrite();
            break; 
        }
        case 2:
        {
            ReadTheCountry();
            break; 
        }
        case 3:
        {
            SortAndDisplayASC();
            break; 
        }
        case 4:
        {
            SortAndDisplayDSC();
            break; 
        }
        case 5:
        {
            SearchForCountry();
            break; 
        }
        case 6:
        {
            CompareDataWithWPOP();
            break; 
        }
    }
}

//6th choise
void CompareDataWithWPOP()
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    long size = fsize(worldData);
    int amount = size / sizeof(data);
    data * countries;
    countries = (data *) malloc(size);
    fread(countries, sizeof(data), amount, worldData);
    long int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i ++)
    {
        sum += countries[i].population;
    }
    float share = (float)sum / WPOP;
    printf("%ld %.2f%%\n", sum, share*100);
    free(countries);
    fclose(worldData);
}

//5th choise
void SearchForCountry( void )
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    long size = fsize(worldData);
    int amount = size / sizeof(data);
    data * countries;
    countries = (data *) malloc(size);
    fread(countries, sizeof(data), amount, worldData);
    findByName(countries, amount);
    free(countries);
    fclose(worldData);
}
void findByName(data * array, int n)
{
    char request[NCHAR];
    fgets(request, NCHAR-1, stdin);
    request[strlen(request)-1] = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if(myStrcmp(request, array[i].country) == 0)
        {
            PrintData(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
int myStrcmp(char * s1, char * s2)
{
    int n = (strlen(s1) < strlen(s2)) ? strlen(s1) : strlen(s2);
    char *temp = (char *) calloc(n+1, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        temp[i] = (strlen(s1) > strlen(s2)) ? s1[i] : s2[i];
    }
    return (strlen(s1) > strlen(s2)) ? strcmp(temp, s2) : strcmp(s1, temp);
}

//4th choise
void SortAndDisplayDSC( void )//main
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    long size = fsize(worldData);
    int amount = size / sizeof(data);
    data * countries;
    countries = (data *) malloc(size);
    fread(countries, sizeof(data), amount, worldData); //PROBLEM HERE!
    sortByPopulation(countries, amount);
    dataArrayFlip(countries, amount);
    for(int i = 0; i < amount;  i ++)
    {
        PrintData(countries[i]);
    }
    free(countries);
    fclose(worldData);
}
void dataArrayFlip(data *array, int length)
{
    data * temp;
    temp = (data *) calloc(length, sizeof(data));
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) temp[i] = array[(length - i) - 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) array[i] = temp[i];
    free(temp);
}

//3rd choise
void SortAndDisplayASC( void )//main
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    long size = fsize(worldData);
    int amount = size / sizeof(data);
    data * countries;
    countries = (data *) malloc(size);
    fread(countries, sizeof(data), amount, worldData); //PROBLEM HERE!(no problem now)
    sortByPopulation(countries, amount);
    for(int i = 0; i < amount;  i ++)
    {
        PrintData(countries[i]);
    }
    free(countries);
    fclose(worldData);
}
long fsize(FILE * f)
{
    long lenght;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    lenght = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return lenght;
}
void sortByPopulation(data *array, int n)
{
    //sorts countries in asceding order by population
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i ++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j ++)
        {
            if(array[i].population > array[j].population)
            {
                dataArrayItemSwap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
void dataArrayItemSwap(data *array, int a, int b)
{
    //changes places of 2 items in an array
    data temp = array[b];
    array[b] = array[a];
    array[a] = temp;
}

//2nd choise
void ReadTheCountry( void )//main
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
    //test if file is a true thing
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int n;
    //get the country number to read(start form 0)
    scanf("%d%*c", &n);
    //caculating the position
    int offset = sizeof(data) * n;
    //moving to that position
    fseek(worldData, offset, SEEK_SET);
    data Country;
    //reading data form that position
    fread(&Country, sizeof(data), 1, worldData);
    PrintData(Country);
    fclose(worldData);
}
void PrintData(data subject)
{
    //prints name, population and world share and starts a new line
    printf("%-16s\t%10ld\t\t%5.2f%%\n", subject.country, subject.population, subject.world_share * 100);
}

//1st choise
void EnterAndWrite( void )//main
{
    FILE * worldData;
    worldData = fopen("world.dat", "ab");
    //test if file can be acsessed
    if(worldData == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //get data to append the file
    data Country;
    ScanData(&Country);
    //go to the end of file
    fseek(worldData, 0, SEEK_END);
    fwrite(&Country, sizeof(data), 1, worldData);
    fclose(worldData);
}
void ScanData(data * subject)
{
    //get name
    fgets(subject->country, NCHAR-1, stdin);
    subject->country[strlen(subject->country)-1] = '\0';
    //get population
    scanf("%ld%*c", &subject->population);
    //find world share
    subject->world_share = (float)subject->population / WPOP;
    //end of the function;
}
```

This piece of code worked with world.dat file, where structures describing countries were saved in binary. I have converted it to base64 and you are free to construct it back.

```
Q2hpbmEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqIJW3/5/AAAQ9+BhGX8AAIBWylUAAAAAF/U8PgAAAABJbmRpYQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACoglbf/n8AABD34GEZfwAAITJBUgAAAAB4KzU+AAAAAFVuaXRlZCBTdGF0ZXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKiCVt/+fwAAEPfgYRl/AAAbs7oTAAAAAJ/RLT0AAAAASW5kb25lc2lhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqOKfpf9/AAAQd1Kbw38AAJ+jTRAAAAAAjaIPPQAAAABQYWtpc3RhbgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACo4p+l/38AABB3UpvDfwAAtIwqDQAAAABc/uc8AAAAAEJyYXppbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKjin6X/fwAAEHdSm8N/AAA5ZqsMAAAAAO093zwAAAAATmlnZXJpYQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqOKfpf9/AAAQd1Kbw38AAMVwSQwAAAAA2n/YPAAAAABCYW5nbGFkZXNoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACo4p+l/38AABB3UpvDfwAA5/XQCQAAAABR96w8AAAAAFJ1c3NpYQAAc2gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKjin6X/fwAAEHdSm8N/AAB+yLIIAAAAAMNEmTwAAAAATWV4aWNvAABzaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqOKfpf9/AAAQd1Kbw38AAJFbrwcAAAAAlmmHPAAAAABKYXBhbgAAAHNoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACo4p+l/38AABB3UpvDfwAAreCJBwAAAAAt1YQ8AAAAAEV0aGlvcGlhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKjin6X/fwAAEHdSm8N/AACENNoGAAAAAIR7cTwAAAAAUGhpbGlwcGluZXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqOKfpf9/AAAQd1Kbw38AABYTiAYAAAAALS1mPAAAAABFZ3lwdAAAaW5lcwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACo4p+l/38AABB3UpvDfwAAxH8ZBgAAAABo9FY8AAAAAFZpZXRuYW0AAGVzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKjin6X/fwAAEHdSm8N/AADTRM0FAAAAAP91TDwAAAAAQ29uZ28AAAAAZXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqOKfpf9/AAAQd1Kbw38AADuZVgUAAAAA9x88PAAAAABUdXJrZXkAAABlcwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACo4p+l/38AABB3UpvDfwAAe+kGBQAAAADBJzE8AAAAAElyYW4AAAAAAGVzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKjin6X/fwAAEHdSm8N/AAB1oQEFAAAAAKNtMDwAAAAAR2VybWFueQAAZXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqOKfpf9/AAAQd1Kbw38AAAZx/gQAAAAAP/0vPAAAAABUaGFpbGFuZAAAcwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACo4p+l/38AABB3UpvDfwAAKhApBAAAAAChnRI8AAAAAA==
```

MD5 of original file:

```
c2c0571518b47973f719f5dba96621dc
```

SHA256 of original file:

```
10ba4a9bc275b2c12f1b1f52fefc124d83df4485fe24c40ffcf5ca97830f1721
```

So, as far as I remember, there was a bug in fsize function that returned wrong size of a file in one weird case. This version should be with out the bug.

Thanks everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: What is the actual format of the file, is it really a raw binary file, where the data is stored as the shown structures? Or is the data stored as text?

Comment: You need to explain what's in the file. Unless the structure matches *exactly* this won't work.

Comment: And have you tried to check for error returned from the `fread` call? What does it return? What happens if you print the "data" without doing the sorting? Have you checked (i.e. in a debugger) that the data in `countries` is correctly read? Are you sure that the `fsize` function works correctly?

Comment: And here's a general tip to make working code: Don't write a lot of it in one go! Divide and conquer instead, by writing a very small piece or simple code following [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Then *test* it, build with verbose warnings, treat them as errors, fix them. Test for different inputs etc. Only when the small piece of simple code works you continue to add the next little small and simple piece of code.

Comment: Provide a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for checking!  If you want see the whole picture, there is [my code](https://pastebin.com/2VWeuViv) and [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mW7fUNVzqMJxLqr8LiM8N5R-41b86TjU/view) i use for testing, it is a simple binary file with the size of 1600bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of your complete code and data: I recreated the missing part of the program and added some comments to the code to ease code-review:

- receives sample data (5 records) from user,
- writes it to a binary file (world.dat),
- reads the data from the file,
- sort the
  data by population and list it.

It compiles and run well on my machine (gcc - Wall), you can go through it and compare to your code; hope this helps you.

The below is output of the program after sorting:

```
Sort is completed successfully using bubble-sorting technique!
Country: D - Population: 5 - World Share: 2 %
Country: C - Population: 20 - World Share: 8 %
Country: A - Population: 50 - World Share: 20 %
Country: E - Population: 80 - World Share: 31 %
Country: B - Population: 100 - World Share: 39 %
```

Please, be aware that if your data file doesn't reflect the struct accurately, it shall not produce the correct data.

```
/** by: moemen.ahmed 
 * date: 16 May 20
 * reference to stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830512/how-can-i-make-fread-work-properly-in-c-it-fills-my-dynamic-array-with-zeroes 
 * purpose: collect and store countires population input in a binary file, then re-read the file, and sort it by population.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCHAR 64

// define the main Country struct
typedef
    struct Country_
    {
        char country[NCHAR];
        long int population;
        float world_share;
    }
Country;

// store countries count in a global variable
int count = 0;
// store total population in a global variable
long int totalPopulation = 0;
// declare a global pointer that will point to the start of data-blocks

// functions declaration
// receives the user input and store it in memory
void addCountry();
// update the world_share% in each of the structs in memory
void updateWorldShare();
// list countries data from memory
void listCountries();
// write the list of countries to the file world.dat
void writeCountries(); 
// read the data from the file to memory
void readCountries ();
// calculate the number of records in the file; update the global variable 'count'
int fsize(FILE* file); 
// sort the records in the memory
void sortCountriesByPopulation();

// main function
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 5) {
        addCountry();
        x += 1;
    }
    updateWorldShare();
    listCountries();
    writeCountries();
    // let us reset the data, so everything comes from reading the file afterwards.
    free(countries);
    totalPopulation = 0;
    count = 0;
    // read the binary file
    readCountries();
    sortCountriesByPopulation();
    listCountries();
    free(countries);
    return 0;
}

void listCountries(){
    // int count = getCountriesCount();
    Country* currCountry;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        currCountry = countries + (i * sizeof(Country));
        printf("Country: %s - Population: %ld - World Share: %0.00f %%\n", currCountry->country, (long int) currCountry->population, (float) currCountry->world_share * 100);
    }
    return;
}


void addCountry()
{
    Country new;
    printf("Enter Country Name.");
    scanf("%s", new.country);
    printf("Enter Population.");
    scanf("%ld", &new.population); 
    // ignore calculating world-share% during input.
    new.world_share = 0.0;
    countries = (Country *) realloc( countries, (count + 1) * sizeof(Country));
    *(countries + (count ) * sizeof(Country)) = new;
    // update the goabl count and totalPopulation
    totalPopulation += new.population;
    count += 1;
    return ;
}

void updateWorldShare(long int population){
    printf("... updadting world share %% \n");
    printf("... total population : %ld\n", (long int) totalPopulation);
    Country* currCountry;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        currCountry = countries + (i * sizeof(Country));
        currCountry->world_share = ((float) currCountry->population )/ ((float) totalPopulation);
    }
    return;
}

void updateTotalPopulation(){
    printf("... updadting TotalPopulation\n");
    totalPopulation = 0;
    Country* currCountry;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        currCountry = countries + (i * sizeof(Country));
        totalPopulation += currCountry->population; 
    }
    printf("... total population : %ld\n", (long int) totalPopulation);
    return;
}

void sortCountriesByPopulation(){
    printf("... sorting countries by population, Count: %d\n", count);
    Country *xCountry, *yCountry;
    for (int i = 0; i < (count - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (count - 1 - i ); j++) {
            xCountry = countries + (j * sizeof(Country));
            yCountry = countries + ((j+1) * sizeof(Country));
            if (xCountry->population > yCountry->population){
                // do a swap
                Country tempCountry; 
                tempCountry = *xCountry;
                *xCountry = *yCountry;
                *yCountry = tempCountry;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sort is completed successfully using bubble-sorting technique!\n");

    return;
}

void readCountries(void)//main
{
     printf("reading ...... \n");
     FILE * worldData;
     worldData = fopen("world.dat", "rb");
     if(worldData == NULL)
     {
         printf("NO FILE CAN BE ACSESSED\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     long size = fsize(worldData);
     count = size / sizeof(Country);
     Country * countries;
     countries = (Country *) malloc(size);
     fread(countries, sizeof(Country), count, worldData); 
     fclose(worldData);
     updateTotalPopulation();
     return;
}

int fsize(FILE* file) {
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    return size;
}


void writeCountries( void) 
{
     FILE * worldData;
     worldData = fopen("world.dat", "wb");
     fwrite(countries, sizeof(Country), count, worldData); 
     fclose(worldData);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for checking! Your code really helped my and i've found the mistake(really stupid mistake, should've written fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); at the end of fsize() function)! If you want see the whole picture, there is my code [link](https://pastebin.com/2VWeuViv) and the file i use for testing [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mW7fUNVzqMJxLqr8LiM8N5R-41b86TjU).

Comment: glad it helped!